# How do I move an element out of its parent element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ning

In the example below, using jQuery, how would I move `.nav` out of `.header` and append it to `.container`?

So this is *before*:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="nav"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this would be *after*:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried, but it's not working.

`<script>
 $( "div.container" ).append( $( ".nav" ) );
</script>`

Note: It's on a Ning site, and the script above was inserted into the custom code section in the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct for appending the element and get desired dom. However you have not called it at correct place. write the code on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "div.container" ).append($(".nav"));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)/[.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)/[.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) are the driods you're looking for.

If you're still having trouble, have a look at [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).